# htaccess isn't redirecting as intended

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am stuck at a problem with my htaccess file.

Normally I'd just put the likes

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /path/and/more/stuff/filename.doc http://www.domain.tld/
```

into the htaccess and it would redirect my user that opens the path on my Domain that no longer exists to the main domain.

I have tried also already

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /path/and/more/stuff/filename.doc http://www.domain.tld/?
```

but the result was the same.

But for some reason my htaccess completely ignores me here. Wordpress is working as normal. I have added the code in the Top of the htaccess by now but still it just redirects me to the 404 error Page of Wordpress http://www.domain.tld/path/and/more/stuff ..

What am i missing here?

Proxy server that I use for testing show the same result (had before some lines for caching in the htaccess too, but they are by now all removed)

Complete htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /path/and/more/stuff/filename.doc http://www.domain.tld/?
Redirect 301 /path/filename.pdf http://www.domain.tld/?
Redirect 301 /path/and/filename.xls http://www.domain.tld/?
Redirect 301 /path/and/more http://www.domain.tld/?

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I BELIEVE i did it the right way, other blogs of me work fine with that kind of redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `Redirect` directive. Try these rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^path/(and/more/stuff|filename\.pdf) http://www.domain.tld/? [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Great, the files i could all redirect nicly now. Just one redirection isn't working: http://www.domain.tld/vb .. because it is just a folder? had added it with `RewriteRule ^vb/ http://www.domain.tld/? [L,NC,R=302]` but that seems not to be the right way then :(

Comment: Does `/vb/` folder have a separate .htaccess? Otherwise `RewriteRule ^vb/? http://www.domain.tld/? [L,NC,R=302]` should work just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: DOH, i haven't even thought about to just create the folder and add a htaccess that just redirects EVERYTHING back to the site. That would solve a lot of writing work that just came up (found 200+ files that needed to get redirected. Thank you very much for that reminder.. should work wonders ;)